# Is it possible to handle memcached memory geting overflow?

Tags: perl, memcached

I have a serious problem my memcached memory is overflow and server is getting down.
So how to handle memcached, If memcached memory is getting full then it will just throw error msg, not set the memcached anymore.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are asking. If it throws an exception as you say, and you're asking how to catch that exception, you can use `eval BLOCK`.

Comment: Or [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try::Tiny).

Answer (score 0):

memcached is distributed cache system and can be works on different servers. What is your server? is it couchebase, is it elastic cache of AWS? you can use memcache on many different server and providers and when you are creating those servers you need to configure them and set the size of memory you want memcache to use. for example in the company I am working, the test environment uses couchbase but the live uses Amazon Elastic cache. 
Memcached uses LRU (least recently used) algorithm to insert the new object into the memory if the table is full. You should not have problem because of full memory and handling memcached. The problem can raise from the full memory but not with this reason that memcached cannot handle it. Exceptions and other problem can be in other part of the system which is quite normal if your memory is full. if you configure the server correctly memcache usually does not throw exception.

Is the server that runs memcached same as the server that runs your application? Memcached can be put on another server and in this way you can prevent the memory to become full.